# Why is the malware programme tag my winforms application as a Gen:Variant.Strictor.134774

Tags: c#, malware, malware-detection

Firstly I did not decide where I must ask my question. I coded a Winforms project that it uses an SQLite database. The programme realizes adding, updating and deleting processes. If not exist, create folder and copies some files in it from application folder. Same way, creates new *.docx file and later opens it. My application never requires Internet connection or never connects to Internet.

I finished the project and installed to Program Files (x86) folder. Shortly before, IObit Malware Fighter tag my winforms application as a Gen:Variant.Strictor.134774. Here is the screenshot:
[image]

I don't know that how I can solve the problem.

**EDIT:** When I remove the application icon, I noticed that the malware error left. But still, I did not understand, why?

Comment: You need to talk to the people who make that virus scanner, we can't help.

Comment: @DavidG, David, I said something in the edit section. I think maybe there are some things that people can help or say something about it.

Comment: Removing the icon just changes the signature of the app. You could equally have changed some of the text in the app or whatever. Literally the only people that can understand why it was flagged are the people who make the virus scanner.

Comment: I would like to say that you are absolutely right about this. _"Literally the only people that can understand why it was flagged are the people who make the virus scanner"_.Who knows, maybe if someone faces such this problem, he should think about replacing the app icon (*.ico) with an original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Report it as a [false positive](https://www.iobit.com/product-manuals/imf-help/#Report%20False%20Positive) to the manufacturer. Errors like these usually stem from protectors or obfuscators which do work similar to what a malicious application would do to hide from an antivirus product. anti virus scanners also use heuristics which sometimes check for specific API calls that are known to be used by malware such as querying the keyboard state globally.